# Как прочитать txt-файл из ресурсов?

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как воспользоваться файлом `(.txt)` в коде, который находится в `Resources` проекта.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если верить аналогичному [ответу на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file), то

Вы можете использовать [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=VS.85).aspx) метод:

1. Добавьте следующий using

   ```
   using System.Reflection;
   ```
2. Установите следующее свойство у нужного файла:

   Параметр `Build Action`, значение `Embedded Resource`
3. Использовать следующий код

   ```
   var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
   var resourceName = "MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt";

   using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
   using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
   {
       string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
   }
   ```

`resourceName` имя ресурса встроенного в сборку. Например, если добавляется файл  *"MyFile.txt"*, который лежит в корне проекта с неймспейсом по умолчанию *"MyCompany.MyProduct"*, тогда `resourceName` будет *"MyCompany.MyProduct.MyFile.txt"*.
Если нужно получить список всех ресурсов в сборке можно воспользоваться методом [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).